# Is it normal to have lots of methods in a php class?

Tags: php, methods

I'm working on a php class for form validation that validated different things like, empty, length etc..

Here are couple of methods I've there. As the title says, is it normal to have bunch of methods in a class? ***Just an answer in yes or no would be enough.***

```
//Checks if is username empty
        function validate_empty_username(){
            if($this->empty_username){
                echo "<li>Please fill username field</li>";
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Checks if is password empty
        function validate_empty_password(){
            if($this->empty_password){
                echo "<li>Please fill password field</li>";
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Checks if is email empty
        function validate_empty_email(){
            if($this->empty_email){
                echo "<li>Please fill email field</li>";
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Check username length is short
        function validate_username_length_min(){
            if($this->get_username_length < 3){
                echo "<li>Username provided's too short!</li>";
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Check password length if short
        function validate_password_length_min(){
            if($this->get_password_length < 5){
                echo "<li>Password provided's too short!</li>";
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Check email length if short
        function validate_email_length_min(){
            if($this->get_email_length < 5){
                echo "<li>Email provided's too short!</li>";
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ofcourse it is, as long the methods are related to the class.

Comment: A lot of your methods here seem to be very very related, I would have probably popped all of them together under a "check email" call - but having said that, there is nothing wrong with having loads of things classes can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not `lots`... As long as it makes sense and doesn't violate principles, you're OK. Just follow programming rules and OOP.

These methods you've shown are clearly somewhat related and it's not a problem if you put them into one class. I think it would be much worse if this logic would be spread all over your source code.

Comment: cant vote-up, @walther 15 rep's needed.
But thanks for the answer : )

Comment: @1to1k, no problem, you can come back and vote later ;) Btw, if you need help optimizing your code, we have a nice site for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's like that: you start writing your classes, then you come back to add something to a method, then you might extend your class by a similar functionality, and finally you end up realizing, that it became dirty and there are many things, you could merge into a single (private) function to not only reduce the length of your code, but also make it easier to maintain.

So my advice: always take a second, think of what you're going to do, and whether the method you're going to implement is a chain of sub-functions, which on their own would be useful somewhere else. Try to make your functions as atomic as possible, but only declare the ones needed as public.

Comment: hey @Robert  .  Mate I'm trying to put similar methods inside a function but when i call this function the methods inside it aren't called what should i do so that when i call the function the methods inside it are called too? thanks

Comment: @1to1k if you are using nested functions (functions inside functions, or in your case functions inside a method) and you are using variables/objects like "$this" then you have to pass that variable/object ("$this") as a parameter to the function inside your method, otherwise the function can't be executed. that's probably your problem.(btw "$this" is an object pointer)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will be using all of those validation functions at once, so I would recommend putting them all together.

But generally you can have as many functions in a class as you want, but eventually you get to a point where you have so many functions that instead of making code simpler you are just making a big mess.

I would put only unrelated code in separate functions. Because when you have similar parts of code it's often easier to code it in a single function.

Comment: I think I will make 3 more functions and put all the similar functions inside them. Like check_email will have couple of functions lets says check_length check_length etc..

Because atm I'm calling methods one by one.. What I might aswell do is call one main methods, like check_email and then call others(check_length.. check_empty) methods from inside it.

Does it sound like a good idea or am I missing something here?

@zoran404 how do I deleted my question.. people're starting to -rep whatever me.. need to remove it before i lose ability to post more questions

Comment: Of course you will use those 1 by 1, but if you will always use them in the same order then there is no need to use multiple functions, but if you do it that way it is not a mistake either. (and if you want to delete the question there is a delete button on the bottom of it, just under the tags, altho you don't need to do it since you have positive points on it; and you can also upvote now)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.As long as the methods in class are related it's good to go.And your's is a very short list.You can use [GUMP Validator](https://packagist.org/packages/wixel/gump) if you want to validate.It's very simple to use too.

Comment: hey @user3107673 .  Mate I'm trying to put similar methods inside a function but when i call this function the methods inside it aren't called what should i do so that when i call the function the methods inside it are called too? thanks

Comment: @1to1k can you plz share your code.

Comment: here mate. i changed a code according to what i was talking about. http://pastebin.com/FQM7dAux @user3107673

Comment: @1to1k there's a syntax error { missing. Other then that I could instantiate the class and all functions were working fine.A good practice is to put a echo in every function for checking if all functions are called which you can remove later.Let me know what error you got.